# How to get out from endless loop in c

Tags: c

i'm trying to bubble sort a string, and it's working, but i can't think of a way to exit this endless loop.
please help!

```
do {
    for (k = i; angrm1[k + 1] != ' '&&angrm1[k + 1] != 0; k++) {
        if (angrm1[i] > angrm1[i + 1]) {
            temp = angrm1[k];
            angrm1[k] = angrm1[k + 1];
            angrm1[k + 1] = temp;
            flag = 1;
        }i++;
    }
    if (angrm1[i+1] == ' ')
        i = i + 2;
    if (angrm1[i+1] == '\0')
        i = 0;
} while (flag != 0);
```

Comment: Ever thought of `break`?

Comment: I think the first thing you should figure out is *why* it is endless?

Comment: @narusin There is a stop condition already. It just should be hit.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know there is a stop condition, but it appears like the user isn't able to break out of the loop

Comment: @narusin Yes, but apparently it's not like he is trapped there and want to break free at any cost :) The code still has to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop is caused by not having a condition to set `flag = 0`.

Here is a cleaner version that depends on `i` and not `i` and `k`. I'll leave the spaces for you to implement.

```
do {
  //Set flag to zero
  flag = 0;
  for(i = 0; angrm1[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(angrm1[i+1] == '\0'){
       //If end of string, exit the loop by breaking
       break;
    }
    if(angrm1[i] > angrm1[i+1]){
          temp = angrm1[i];
          angrm1[i] = angrm1[i+1]; 
          angrm1[i+1] = temp;
          flag = 1;
       }
    }
    i = 0;
} while (flag != 0);
```